# Inductive and resistive load current draw - PSU

Tags: power-supply, load, inductive

Below schematic is a simplified version of a power supply:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhNmJ0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the voltage is set to 12V and current limit is set to 100 mA and output is connected to a resistive load (10 ohm), the current pulled from the supply is exactly 100 mA. but when an inductive load is connected (brushless fan) it only pulls 75 mA from the supply.

Why inductive load draws less current when there's room for it to draw more? Is it because of it's inductive properties or I should look for the source of the problem in the circuit?

Comment: Why should it take more than 100 mA? It depends on what it is and what it’s effective resistance is.

Comment: Its not it’s, stupid spelling killer.

Comment: @Andyaka not more than 100mA but the actual 100mA.

Comment: How much does it take when the current isn't limited?  I bet 75mA.  This circuit keeps you from drawing more than 100mA, but it doesn't prevent you from drawing less.  Your 10 ohm resistor would draw 1200mA if not current limited to 100mA, but a 160 ohm resistor would draw only 75mA either way.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis it draws ~120mA when current is not limited.

Comment: @ElectronSurf In that case we'll need more details on how you're measuring the current and how your current sense mechanism works, preferably schematics for at least the latter.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis I'm sure of the current reading, so you think it might be an issue in the circuit?

Comment: Without knowing how the circuit works, I have no idea, but it seems likely.  Pop up a schematic of the current sense subsystem.  Are you measuring with an inline meter, a current probe, or something else?

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis I'm sensing the current over a 1 ohm resistor with 3 op amps configured as instrumentation amplifier. so I can measure the current at the output of the in-amp and also with a multimeter. both readings are the same.

Comment: @Andyaka I added the schematic, can you please take a look at it? any problem that might need mentioning?

Comment: Your buffer on the output has no DC feedback path due to the 1uF cap.  That'll keep the slew rate down, but it's still infinite gain at DC.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis It's a comparator, can't just connect the non-inverting input to the output. even removing that RC doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @ElectronSurf A comparator isn't the right tool here, unless your plan is to switch the supply on and off rapidly like a buck regulator.  Its output is basically digital.  An op amp will work better.  The reason your feedback circuits aren't doing much is because they have a high impedance compared to what's driving the negative input (output voltage in one case, op amp output direct in the other).

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis So what is your suggestion? how can an op amp switch to current mode? how I can *compare* the reference voltage and the current other than using a comparator?

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis Oh sorry I get it now, I meant it's configured as an comparator not an actual comparator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are detecting Peak current and not Average Current as should be  !! Where are your specs????

A BLDC fan acts like a resistive load ONLY when you average the current over a specific time interval such that there is no ripple in the Avg current measurement.  **As such, the fan current increases linearly with voltage above the start speed due to RPM fan load.**

The storage Caps "can" provide most of the ripple current if rated you wanted that otherwise use your regulator for it and define a filter with peak ripple % vs f , as you like.

Yet your current sense amplifies peak pulse current with 10ms  average which is too short an Tau or too little attenuation of peak/average current ratio. Therefore you need to know the pulse frequency and filter rejection at that freq to obtain an error of peak to average.  Then understand the consequences.

If max RPM is 3600 = 60 Hz and current pulses are 2x = 120 Hz and you want current measured in 100ms to be 1% error max then you need a filter of -40dB at 120 Hz with a group delay of 100ms max.

Are these assumptions acceptable? **Do you know how to design a LPF?**

Consider
[image]  instead of your [image]

Comment: What specs should I add? How can I detect average current?

Comment: You Must Define a LIST of Specs: All Input Ranges , All output ranges.  Ripple, Step load Overshoot, Pulse current attenuation % or dB @ freq like any LP filter.   Load Regulation Error.% Step Load Error 50 to 100% to 50% I @ TBD % V error.    These are your Design Acceptance criteria. Look around at professional PSU Specs. They have more ...but this is minimal.

Comment: I don't know what most of those are and how to measure it! the input is 24V, for op amps it's +24V/-5V. there's no ripple (as far as my crappy scope can measure) and no over/undershot when going to CC mode or recovering from it and also when turning on/off the PSU. output voltage is 0-20V 1A.

Comment: You don't know I max or Vmin or Ictrl, input? Then you are not ready to design and must go back to reading/learning. Do you know how to define a stepload and measure error?

Comment: I did added the input/output voltage/current, I just don't know how to measure this: "Load Regulation Error.% Step Load Error 50 to 100% to 50% I @ TBD % V error."

Comment: "Do you know how to define a stepload and measure error?" no I don't, sorry... can you please guide me?

Comment: A NPN with current gain can switch a base current with switch or signal generator to make a step load of any 2 levels.   But do you understand how to regulate LDO properly and how it works in figure 2 and figure 23,25 https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/LM317-D.PDF  When I design one , I used an NPN to pulldown Vadj, not a diode. and it had a controlled current and voltage gain.

Comment: My first design was that actually, an NPN transistor with emitter connected to -5V pulling down the ADJ pin. but that use to oscillate when it was in CC mode. this design is more stable compared to that one. the only problem is what I described in the question. it can't drive an inductive load properly.

Comment: Then you had too much loop gain which could have been corrected by reducing 1 Ohm . You need a proper filter.

Comment: Any idea what can I do for this specific design?

Comment: Tony I know I'm so annoying sometimes, but you're so kind teaching me patiently. THANK YOU! the LPF fixed it, I just changed the 1uF to 4.7uF. working like a charm now.

Comment: some day you will do what I suggest. Make specs. Then implement

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but brushless motor is a complex load. It has electronic commutator which switches the input voltage to the winding or windings which currently are best to keep the motor running. The load is not pure inductance, there are controlled switches in series and the controller itself. If your current limiter causes voltage drops they can disturb the controller. Your system can oscillate. If you have an oscilloscope, check does the voltage stay stable. Anything written without having your system is only guessing.

If you have a big inductor, say the secondary winding of a few voltage output AC mains transformer, you can check what pure inductive load causes.

WARNING: removing the DC from the coil by disconnecting a wire causes a disastrous high voltage peak. It can be for ex. 15000 volts and punches the insulation of the transformer. Or something which happens to have contact with the transformer get a fatal shock. Be sure that the wires do not get disconnected nor make bad contact as long as there's power on in the system. If you happen to be a beginner do not try this!

Comment: It is oscillating when the fan is connected and is in current limit mode like crazy, so the odd behavior is because of the circuitry inside the brushless fan?

Comment: It's well possible that a pure inductor also could cause oscillation if the PSU circuitry isn't designed for inductive load. I guess (read GUESS) it's the control circuitry which doesn't stand voltage drops.

Comment: Can you please direct me to a link or give me a keyword to google on how can I design/improve the PSU to be able to control inductive load as well as resistive load?

Comment: Start by inserting a diode to the output of the PSU. Let it be in parallel with the load but reversed so that it only sucks the inductive current that the inductor tries to keep on going when PSU's control circuit tries to cut the current off. Check how this power opamp OPA544 is applied. It's designed for driving coils and motors http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sbos038/sbos038.pdf which

Comment: Thanks, added the schematic to the question. appreciate it if you please take a look at it.

Comment: Just saw your schematic. It has 2 long high gain feedback routes which both try to pull the Uout downwards in case they see there's too much voltage or current. It's difficult to make this stable even with resistive loads. There's a well known circuit where one LM317 works as input current limiter for another which works as series voltage regulator - this: https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/LM317-D.PDF If you want to improve your existing circuit Texas Instrument at least gives a model of LM317 for their TINA free network analyzer. You maybe could tune the dynamics of your circuit with it.

Comment: When I first started building this PSU my goal was to be able to control it digitally, that two LM317 configuration can't have this ability. any tip or idea to improve this design? I figured that if I add a 10uF capacitor to the output of OP07 it can solve the problem but on the other hand it will slow down (a bit) switching to CC mode.

Comment: *Correction: a 10uF capacitor the output of the current comparator.*

Comment: @ElectronSurf  You have already another answer which has an attempt to make the dynamics better for motor current limiting. Try it. I guess the writer has more in practice proven experience than me.